# Prisms and light outside the visible spectrum

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Can a prism, of the proper material for a range of frequencies outside of the visible spectrum, but of interest, be constructed that will separate those frequencies, in that range,  in a manner analogous to the visible light prism`s operation? [image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infra red part of the spectrum was first discovered when a thermometer showed an increase in reading when placed beyond the red end of the spectrum of sunlight.

So the answer to you question is "yes".

What is required is a dispersive material (speed of wave depends on frequency) which does not absorb the radiation and a suitable detector.

If a glass prism is replaced by a prism made of calcium fluoride then the infra red radiation can be detected over a greater range of frequencies because infra red is absorbed less by calcium fluoride than by glass.

Ultra violet (beyond the violet part of the spectrum) can be detected using a fluorescent screen and is more noticeable if a quartz prism is used.

A paraffin wax prism will refract microwaves but the prism must be much larger than the wavelength of the microwaves so as to mask the effect of diffraction.